# KNight MOVe shortest

Tags: algorithm, recursion, shortest-path, backtracking

MY code is here: Question is to find min number of moves to go from one sq. to other in 8*8 chess board .

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int n;
    int a[12][12];
    int min1=1000,xd=5,yd=2,ys,xs,xsi,ysi;

    int find_path(int xs,int ys)
    {
        cout<<xs<<"  "<<ys<<endl;
    if((xs==xd) && (ys==yd)) {  cout<<"destiny schieved  "<<endl; return 0;}      
    if(a[xs][ys]==1 || xs<0 || ys<0 || xs>7 || ys>7) return 10000;
    a[xs][ys]=1;
    int a1=1+(find_path(xs-2,ys+1)) ;
    int b=1+(find_path(xs-2,ys-1)) ;
    int c=1+(find_path(xs-1,ys+2)) ;
    int d=1+(find_path(xs-1,ys-2)) ;
    int d=1+(find_path(xs+2,ys+1)) ;
    int e=1+(find_path(xs+2,ys-1)) ;
    int f=1+(find_path(xs+1,ys+2)) ;
    int g=1+(find_path(xs+1,ys-2)) ;
    a[xs][ys]=0;
    return min(a1,b,c,d,e,f,g);
    }


    int main()
    {
        int i,j,k;

        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
        a[i][j]=0;

  cout<<"start"<<endl;

  cout<<find_path(0,7);

      system("pause");
        return 0;
        }
```

This is my code for traversing from one square to other in 8*8 chess board .
MY code gives wrong answer for some cases :

a[xs][ys]=1; is for preventing loops.
for eg answer for  (0,7) ->>>> (5,2) is 4 but my algo gives 38 . MY  coordinate axis are X: from left to right and Y-axis: from top to bottom . Please help me solving my problem.

Few solutions are:

(7,0) ->>> (0,7)   : 6
(0,7)  ->>> (5,2)  :4

I have also tried another code which i later edited to get the above code:

```
  int find_path(int xs,int ys,int path)
    {
        cout<<xs<<"  "<<ys<<endl;
    if((xs==xd) && (ys==yd)) { if(min1>path) min1=path; cout<<"destiny schieved  "<<path<<endl; return 1;}      
    if(a[xs][ys]==1 || xs<0 || ys<0 || xs>7 || ys>7) return 0;
    a[xs][ys]=1;
    if(find_path(xs-2,ys+1,path+1)) {if(path==0) {cout<<"i am on start1"<<endl;} else return 1;}
    if(find_path(xs-2,ys-1,path+1)) {if(path==0) {cout<<"i am on start2"<<endl;} else return 1; }
    if(find_path(xs-1,ys+2,path+1)) {if(path==0) {cout<<"i am on start3"<<endl;} else return 1; }
    if(find_path(xs-1,ys-2,path+1)) {if(path==0) {cout<<"i am on start4"<<endl;} else return 1;}
    if(find_path(xs+2,ys+1,path+1)) {if(path==0) {cout<<"i am on start5"<<endl;} else return 1;}
    if(find_path(xs+2,ys-1,path+1)) {if(path==0) {cout<<"i am on start6"<<endl;} else return 1;}
    if(find_path(xs+1,ys+2,path+1)) {if(path==0) {cout<<"i am on start7"<<endl;} else return 1; }
    if(find_path(xs+1,ys-2,path+1)) {if(path==0) {cout<<"i am on start8"<<endl;} else return 1; }
    a[xs][ys]=0;
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often rewarding to think in terms of data structures instead of thinking in terms of algorithms.

In this case, the valid moves for a knight on a board constitute an undirected graph G where vertices denote board positions and edges denote valid moves. Hence, you might have nodes a1 and b3 connected by an edge, since a knight may move from a1 to b3 and vice versa.

Given that representation of the problem, it's fairly easy to compute the min number of moves for a knight to go from A to B, since it's the length of the shortest path from node A to node B in G.

- to compute the shortest path for a given start node and all end nodes, use the Bellman-Ford algorithm with time complexity O(|V||E|).
- to compute the shortest path for all pairs of nodes, use the Floyd-Warshall algorithm with time complexity O(|V|^3).

Comment: bfs costs only `O(E)` while in this problem it's `O(8 * V) = O(V)`...